# retrieve the url path in cakephp

Tags: arrays, database, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to retrieve the 'url' path of  a picture. I have an issue with the variable $media it's not supposed to be empty

the DB table 'Media' has this

```
id|name|url|posts_id|type
```

MediaController.php

```
function admin_show($id = null){
    if($id){
        $this->Media->id = $id;
        $media = current($this->Media->read());
        echo 'results for $media'."\n";
        debug($media);
        $d['url'] = Router::url('/img/'.$media['url']);//for the Absolute URL
        echo 'results for $d'."\n";
        debug($d);
    }
    //I added this line to check if there is any contents in the "Table"
    $results = $this->Media->find('all');
    echo 'results for $results'."\n";
    debug($results);

}
```

and the output looks like this:

```
results for $media
   \app\Controller\MediasController.php (line 47)
false

results for $d
   \app\Controller\MediasController.php (line 50)
  array(
'url' => '/grafikart2/img/'
  )

results for $results
   \app\Controller\MediasController.php (line 54)
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Media' => array(
        'id' => '8',
        'name' => 'media',
        'url' => '2013/11/1003236-10151796510844965-658856574-n.jpg',
        'posts_id' => '1',
        'type' => 'image'
    )
),
```

I'd like to retrieve the $media['url'] in my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thks!

I did this in my Controller instead

```
$resultats = current($this->Media->query("SELECT * FROM medias  where id = $id LIMIT 2;"));
$media = $resultats['medias']['url'];
```

output

```
'2013/11/1003236-10151796510844965-658856574-n.jpg'
```